# Suggestions for block sizes in dask for my matrix (doing onehot and classification)

Tags: python, classification, dask, svc

I am new to using dask, although I have experience in parallel computing and other libraries. I was wondering if someone had good suggestions about which block sizes I should use.

I have the done the following workflow previously in memory using `scikit-learn` with a smaller matrix.  I would like to now scale up using my full dataset.

My matrix will be roughly 4,000 x 2,000,0000 -- and I will be doing the following:

1) Creating the large matrix from 6-8 smaller `numpy` files (I can convert the files to `HDF5` if necessary)

2) Converting the 2,000,000 columns each to a categorical array.  I was thinking I could use the dummy encoder available in `dask-ml`.  Currently, I use the `OneHotEncoder` from `scikit-learn`. For this I would assume a block that was bigger in the column sense would be more useful?

3) Then running the partial `SGD` classifer on the one-hot-matrix.  I want to run with the l1 penalty - so I will be running this a few times to get the optimum value of the C parameter. Note: I am running a model with weights.  For this I would assume that a block that was bigger in the row sense would be more useful?

I have run this previously with my smaller set using just `scikit-learn` to make sure everything works and gives reasonable answers and to tune the parameters for the `SGD` classifer so it gives me the same answers as I got with the linear `SVC`.

My system parameters are pretty flexible since I have access to variety of node types using `Azure`. But, I probably would using a machine with no more than 50-100 Gigs of memory.

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this more of a question for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) or [DataScience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com) communities?

Comment: How many nonzeros are there? I don't expect you need to use out-of-memory processing (which usually should be also very painful for SGD-like algorithms because of random-permutations in each epoch).

Comment: I believe I am following the correct suggestion for questions regarding dask -- "Usage questions are directed to Stack Overflow with the #dask tag. Dask developers monitor this tag and get e-mails whenever a question is asked."  http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/support.html

Comment: Sascha - I am assuming you are asking if I am using sparse matrices. This would be ~64 Gigs of memory without converting to one-hot, I believe. Converting to 1-hot then makes it roughly 5-10 time bigger (if in full matrix form) which is getting me into 640 Gigs.  Even, if it can be sparse (let's say 20% non-zero) -- I end up having to double or triple it for the SVM to work.  This is really hitting a limit for a 50 Gig RAM machine.

Comment: Sascha - also dask (the library I am asking about) has this already implemented, and/or you can do it via the partial fit method in scikit-learn.

Comment: 20% is not sparse. And why should 1-hot encoding increase the size by factor 5-10? It was a simple question: how many nnz / nnz-ratio? And there is no answer. It would surprise me to run into mem-limits. Maybe you got some magic data (2M cols without 1-hot encoding; strange). I'm aware of partial-fit and i'm also aware about what happens if you use it wrong (e.g. not doing permutations; which will cost a lot for out-of-memory approaches). You will have to care about the out-of-memory setup at some place as partial_fit is just one small component expecting something.

Comment: One-hot encoding depends on the number of categorical variables per column (in my case each column is a different categorical variable).  Each variable has approximately 5-10 levels (k) which means each columns is expanded into 5-10 levels.  FYI- since I know my data, and how big it is - this conversations seems not terribly productive.  Dask takes care of the out of memory setup - but that is why I am asking about block size (original question) to avoid unnecessary out-of-memory costs. That was the point of my original question.

Comment: Also, whether or not you think my data is magic, it is common in science to have short and fat matrices, especially in genomics which is where my data comes from. I don't know my nnz ratio value for this particular data since I don't have it loaded in, but from experience previous data is 10-20% which is what I told you above. You can argue whether sparse is useful or not, but again not the point of my question.

Comment: I would like iterate I do not want to argue about my matrix size or the memory it uses or how sparse it is.  I would like advice on how to use Dask and what is the appropriate block size on my short and fat matrix to be as efficient as possible.  I only described my workflow in detail  so that the Dask peeps would have as much info as possible to give their advice.